# Calculate distance between cities & find surrounding cities based on GeoPT, in Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geolocation, distance

I have a cities model defined which saves the `geoname_id` and `location` (as GeoPt) of a city. There are two things that I want to achieve.

1. I want to get all cities within `500km` radius from a given city.
2. I want to calculate distance in `km` between two given cities.

What would be the best way to achieve this, keeping in mind that I have a very large database of cities and I do not want to sacrifice a lot on the performance factor. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works perfect but is a lil slow :

Function to Calculate Distance. The Arguments passed to this function are tuples of latitude and longitude of a location or a Geopt():

```
def HaversineDistance(location1, location2):
  """Method to calculate Distance between two sets of Lat/Lon."""
  lat1, lon1 = location1
  lat2, lon2 = location2
  earth = 6371 #Earth's Radius in Kms.

 #Calculate Distance based in Haversine Formula
 dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
 dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
 a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
 c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
 d = earth * c
 return d
```

Function to calculate Surrounding cities within a radius. This is a method under the City model which store all cities:

```
def get_closest_cities(self, kms):
  cities = []
  #Find surrounding Cities of a given city within a given radius
  allcities = self.country.city_set
  for city in allcities:
    distance = HaversineDistance((self.location.lat, self.location.lon),(city.location.lat, city.location.lon))
    if not distance >= kms:
      cities.append((city.name, int(distance)))
  cities.remove(cities[0])
  return cities
```

Answer (score 3):

Google App Engine doesn't support geospatial queries, but you could refer to [Geospatial Queries with Google App Engine using GeoModel](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geospatial).

You might also want to consider using other databases like `mongoDB` that support [Geospatial Indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) and maybe having it as an external service which does only that.

Comment: i dont really wanna use a seperate library for this as i already have the latitude and longitude of the cities saved in the datastore. Don't you think a simple calculation should do or would you suggest using geomodel ? how would it effect the performance of the application ? Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: There is no other way.. unless you're going to implement your own gespatial indexing.. because GAE simply doesn't support it. You should at least give it a shot with GeoModel. The performance depends on the size of your datastore, and it's definitely going to increase your indexes size. Read through documentation to understand how they are achieving it.

Comment: Thanks Lipis, I will go through it now !

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use something similar to https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/geosearch
2. Just load the locations of the two cities and use trigonometry to compute the distance. See e.g. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html